# Python plotting graph from csv problems

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, graph

[csv file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtXcEqW2iQpCjGnWFi8RveymnQwD?e=03kIMt)

Hello so I have this csv file that I want to convert to a graph, what I want is it to pretty much graph the number of jobs in each region by city. I have the columns for both cities and countries in this csv file, I want to toss out the date created and just have the city and number of job offers.

Here is the code I tried to use and it didn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv ('compuTrabajo_business_summary_by_industry.csv')
sums = df.groupby(df["country;"])["business count"].sum()
axis('equal');
pie(sums, labels=sums.index);
show()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you explain "didn't work"? What didn't work, did you get an error (what error). was the result not what you expected, if so what result did you expect?

Comment: Your CSV file is not comma separated(pipe separated) and has many non UTF-8 characters. You need to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

As Abhinav Kinagi already answered, `pandas` assumes that your values are separated by commas. You can either change your csv-file or simply put `sep='|'`in `pd.read_csv`. Your code should be

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show
df = pd.read_csv ('compuTrabajo_business_summary_by_industry.csv', sep='|')
sums = df.groupby(df["country"])["business count"].sum()
axis('equal');
pie(sums, labels=sums.index);
show()
```

I also removed the ; after country.